# VSCode format on save adding additional tabs in Solidity files

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity

When I save my solidity file in VSCode it adds additional tabs (additional 2 spaces) to all single tabs (2 spaces). Where can I override this? This only happens to my solidity (.sol) files. `Format on save` works correctly for other files e.g. `js` extensions

VSCode settings.json

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false
}
```

Solidity extension I am using is https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vscode-solidity extension uses Prettier for formatting([link](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity#formatting-using-prettier-and-the-prettier-solidity-plugin))

To achieve formatting with 2 spaces:

1. Create a file **.prettierrc**
2. The contents should be

```
    {
       "overrides":[
          {
             "files":"*.sol",
             "options":{
                "tabWidth":2
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

3. Restart VS code